# saving a value to a list every x seconds

Tags: python-3.x, sleep

In Python I need to repeatedly save a value (this changes constantly over time) from a function and save it in a list every x seconds, also I don't want the list to exceed 10 values, but that shouldn't be a problem. The problem is saving these values in the list independent of the rest of the program, meaning i cant have it pausing the rest of the running class while it's saving these values. Is this even possible in Python?

e.g:

```
list = []
while True:
    if len(list) > 9:
        list.pop(0)
    list.append(value)
    sleep(x seconds)
```

Comment: Read about threading and multiprocessing. This lets your program do more things at once so it doesn't hang while waiting.

Comment: Is it possible to use this in a class property?

Comment: Are you talking about the list? Yes, absolutely. It looks like you haven't read about the things I told you yet though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import time
list = []
while True:
    if len(list) > 9:
        list.pop(0)
    list.append(value)
    time.sleep(10)
```

For more visit here : [Python Sleep](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time/sleep)